# Парсинг json полей с точками как классов

Tags: c#, json

Имеется json примерно такого типа:

```
{
  "alarm.event": false,
  "gsm.module.status": true,
  "gsm.network.roaming.status": false,
  "position.altitude": 210.5,
  "position.direction": 0,
  "position.latitude": 50.802413,
  "position.longitude": 35.800086,
  "position.satellites": 18,
  "position.speed": 0,
  "position.timestamp": 1542783744,
  "position.valid": true,
  "timestamp": 1542783737
}
```

Хочется его десериализовать примерно в такой тип:

```
public class Root{
    [JsonProperty("position")]
    public Position Position;
}

public class Position
{
    [JsonProperty("longitude")]
    public double Longitude;
}
```

и так далее, то есть, что бы json конвертер понимал, что первое имя до точки это класс, а далее у него поля. Это реально сделать обойдясь малой кровью? Хочется именно используя метаданные, так-то я понимаю, что можно получить объект со словарем и делать с ним, что хочешь, но хочется коробочную поддержку nullable инициализации если такого класса нет в json, к примеру, а руками это много проверок делать нужно.

Comment: Рассматривали вариант парсера того json в иерхический вид? Например, чтобы из `"gsm.module.status": true,` получить: `"gsm": {"module": {"status": true...`?

Comment: @gil9red, да, в принципе это было бы здорово